# Method never called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

My header

```
@interface WirelessController : UIViewController {
    Server *_server;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) Server *server;
```

My main class

```
@synthesize server = _server;
NSData *data = [@"Some encoded text." dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
/* BOOL test = */ [self.server sendData:data error:nil];
```

I set a breakpoint at the sendData method (inside the server class) but it's never triggered and BOOL test returns false. It appears as if that line is just invisible to the device and doesn't run or something.

**EDIT:**
I didn't link self.server to the originally allocated one (which happens to be an ivar). Any way I can access that ivar?

Comment: Dollars to donuts bbum is right and your `server` value is nil.  NSLog it before the call.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, you're right. I need to get ivar `_server` from another class and use that to call `sendData`

Comment: "Any way I can access that ivar?"  Seems to me that's the question you need to ask yourself.

Comment: @vectorquake, So how are both classes connected? Is it via a push or present?

Answer (score 0):

How do you allocate the server?

Somewhere, there should be a line kinda like:

```
self.server = [[Server alloc] initWithURL:anURL]; // assuming ARC, so implied double retain matters not.
```

(Obviously, replace `initWithURL:` and `Server` with your particular app's details.)

---

OK -- so you have this in some other class:

```
other.server = [[Server alloc] initWithProtocol:type];
```

(1) Sure that is being executed?

(2) In the code that is executing `sendData:`, put an `assert(self.server);` on the line before and try it again (i.e. check if it is nil).

Comment: [[Server alloc] initWithProtocol:type] in another class

Comment: @vectorquake, where are you setting _server to your alloc'd instance of server?